# How to run code through a shell script?

Tags: linux, matlab, shell

I want to run MATLAB code through a linux shell script.

So I've tried

```
#! /usr/bin/tcsh

setenv USER mcevoyd 
setenv LOGNAME mcevoyd 
setenv HOME /home/mcevoyd 
setenv PATH /usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin 
setenv LANG en_US.UTF-8

matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -r "scriptFile.m"
```

but It didn't work.

I saved above shell script as `shell.sh` and ran it on terminal by using `chmod 755 shell.sh`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! For the future - please make sure that your problem is stated clearly in your questions, and does not require others to run your code to see what's wrong with it. What do you mean by "it didn't work"? Does this give an error? Does this not do anything?

Comment: very important clarification: how literally do you mean "...run on terminal by using `chmod 755 shell.sh`"? Because that is definitely not going to run your script.

Comment: @information. Please do not feel free to touch posted code. It is a good thing that you addressed the naming issue in your answer, but please do not change actual code in OP's question. In some cases, it may make the entire question invalid.

Comment: Have you tried running it with `./shell.sh`? After the call to `chmod` of course.

Comment: Also, minor nitpick, but if you do give your script an extension, it would conventionally be `.csh` for a TCSH and CSH scripts. `.sh` is usually used for Bash and similar shells.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It may look like I am modifying code where I am not in this case of the added # sign. Unfortunately, particularly in these shell examples, the markdown behavior of # takes precedent; disappearing and turning non-indented code into a header (i.e. SO is modifying the code).  If it is mainly the change from "code.m" to "scriptFile.m", I'll be sure, going forward, to do that in my post only, with a comment as to why. Thanks for the feedback too.

Comment: @informaton. I was referring only to modifying the variable names. I did not even notice the hash, which is a perfectly reasonable correction in my book.

Answer (score 3):

Change your `matlab` call to:

```
matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -r scriptFile
```

Don't include the `.m` extension or quotation marks (`""`) when the statement following your `-r` flag is a file name (see the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlablinux.html) for more specifics on this).

Note that this will start MATLAB and run your file `scriptFile.m` just as if you had opened MATLAB, and then typed `scriptFile` at the command prompt.  You will remain in the MATLAB environment until you exit.

If you want to run a MATLAB script outside of the MATLAB environment, then you will need to compile it with the [mcc compiler](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/mcc.html).

**p.s.** 
I assume from your post that you changed the permissions of your script file to make it so that it *can be* executable with the call `chmod 755 shell.sh`, but that you actually ran your script with the notation: `./shell.sh`.  Otherwise, this would be an earlier reason your script would not run at all, as opposed to starting but failing to run as you desire.

Comment: I changed your original filename from `code.m` to `scriptFile.m` to prevent confusion from someone seeing `-r code` and thinking `code` is shorthand for MATLAB statements; which are also allowed, provided they are in quotation marks.

Comment: Not sure that this is OP's actual problem, but good answer nevertheless.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks.  I saw your comment above, regarding the literal interpretation of `chmod 777 shell.sh`, and added a postscript for such a case.